# Show that this process is an ARIMA(p,d,q) process for some values of p, d, and q

Tags: self-study, arima

Consider stochastic process given by model equation
\begin{aligned}
Y_t &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + z_t, \\
z_t &= \phi z_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t, \\
\end{aligned}

where $|\phi|<1$.

How do I show that $Y_t$ is an ARIMA($p,d,q$) process for some values of $p, d, $and $q$?

By substituting in our values of $z_{t-1}$ into $z_t$ and continuing in this way isn't that just representing $z_t$ as an MA($\infty$) model? Where does the ARI model appear in that case? Sorry if this seems silly. I think I'm overcomplicating this problem.

$$Y_t - Y_{t-1} = \beta_1 + \phi z_{t-1} - z_{t-1}$$

So this should exist in our $Y_t$ term somewhere?

\begin{align}
Y_t &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \phi z_{t-1} \hspace{20mm} + \varepsilon_t  \\
Y_t &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \phi (\phi z_{t-2} + \epsilon_{t-1}) + \varepsilon_t
\end{align}

I have definitely messed this up somewhere.

Comment: Consider adding the [tag:self-study] tag and reading its [Wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then show us what you have done already and where you got stuck. Also, there is no need to format ARMA as formula ($ARMA$) as it is an acronym, not a function name.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for the edit. I'm not entirely sure as I don't understand how it can have an MA part? As far as I can tell it's dependent on $z_t$ and $t$.

Comment: If you substitute $z_{t}$ in the first equation with its expression from the second equation and continue that way for $z_{t-1}, z_{t-2},\dots$, you will see something interesting. What about the [tag:self-study] tag, though?

Comment: You need to do more than add the tag .. .show what you did and ask about where you got stuck

Comment: But isn't that just representing $z_t$ as an MA(\$\infinity$) model? Where does the ARI model appear in that case? Sorry if this seems silly. I think I'm overcomplicating this problem.

Comment: Note the $d$ in $p,d,q$.... what would that suggest considering?

Comment: It would imply that I need to look at the difference between $Y_t$ and $Y_{t-1}$ right? I'll edit my post.